How do I get my M1 Macbook pro to trust Netskope cert?
My company recently installed Netskope on our machines. Now any HTTP request I make from apps I am running locally fail with the below error whether Netskope is enabled or disabled.
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=******** state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)

I am running Rails apps and the requests fail regardless of the HTTP library I use. I tried manually updating the cert store for the http clients and that works sometimes, but I don't really want to change every request in all our apps. Thanks in advance!
EDIT: I think the root of the issue is that OpenSSL does not trust the cert. I am on version 3.3.0 installed through Brew.

You want to get your Mac to trust a particular certificate for every use on that Mac? There's probably a lot of existing information on the web on how to do this, if you are unsure you might be more likely to get an answer on Ask Different, if it hasn't already been asked and answered there.

As I do some more digging, I think the root issue is openssl. I think I need to get it to trust the Netskope cert.

So it's enough to just get all the Rails apps on your Mac to trust the certificate?

Yes, that should be all I need
